# How to load CSS and images with KnpSnappyBundle PDF and Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I am getting an Authentication Required error on loading CSS and image resources.

Error example:

```
Warning: Failed to load http://reporter.dev:8888/css/fc84af4_part_1_bootstrap-editable_2.css (ignore)
```

I am using the KNP Snappy bundle as follows:

```
$html = $this->renderView(
  'InterlatedReporter:Allocation:casual_calendar_pdf.html.twig',
  array(
    'casualCalendar' => $casualCalendar,
  )
);

$filename = "export-casual-calendar-" . date("Ymd") . '.pdf';

return new Response(
  $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
  200,
  array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'
  )
);
```

The twig template has had absolute paths added to it as follows. The URL's seem to to use file://

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ asset('css/sortable-theme-bootstrap.css') }}
```

I have tried working with security, the dev firewall is in place:

```
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
```

This is the first rule.

We are using controller annotations as per SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.

I have also tried passing the session as per [Symfony 2 kpn snappy generate pdf with output meets security area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286012/symfony-2-kpn-snappy-generate-pdf-with-output-meets-security-area)

How to load the resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a fix. The file:// was the key.

Pass, a base directory to the template:

```
$html = $this->renderView(
  'InterlatedReporter.html.twig',
  array(
    'casualCalendar' => $casualCalendar,
    'base_dir' => $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web' . $request->getBasePath()
  )
);
```

And provide the full path to the assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ base_dir ~ asset('css/sortable-theme-bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and Interlated said, add a base directory before the `asset('path/to/your/asset/or/image')` fix the problem.

If you can't access the `$this->get('kernel')` or `$request` (for example in a listener), you can do it "manually" with the `__DIR__` magic constant !

My listener is in `./my-project/src/MyBundle/Listener/MyListener.php`
and my `$basedir = __DIR__.'/../../../web'`

So in your twig view `<img src="{{ basedir ~ asset('path/to/your/img')}}" alt="">`